# The condition of root == NULL not working in C++

Tags: c++, function, tree, binary-tree

I am a beginner in C++, and am trying to write a program to trace a path between two nodes of a binary tree.
[image: Example of Path Tracing]

An example of Path tracing is given above.
I have written a program to do soo as given below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

struct TreeNode {
  int val;
  TreeNode *left;
  TreeNode *right;
};
 
void getPosition(TreeNode* root, int Value, vector<bool> &list, bool *found) {
    if(root == NULL) {
      return;
    }
    if(root->val == Value) {
        *found = true;
        return;
    }
    cout<<root->val;
    getPosition(root->left, Value, list, found);
    if(*found) {
        list.push_back(true);
        return;
    }
    getPosition(root->right, Value, list, found);
    if(*found) {
        list.push_back(false);
        return;
    }
    return;
}
string getDirections(TreeNode* root, int startValue, int destValue) {
    string Answer;
    vector<bool> start;
    vector<bool> end;  //left = true and right = false;
    bool *condition;
    *condition = false;
    getPosition(root, startValue, start, condition);
    *condition = false;
    getPosition(root, destValue, end, condition);
    int S_size = start.size();
    int E_size = end.size();        
    for(int i=0;i<S_size;i++) {
        cout<<start[i]<<"A";
    }
    int i=0;
    if(S_size == 0) {
        for(int e = E_size - 1;e>=0;e--) {
            if(end[e] == true) {
                Answer.append("R");
            }
            else {
                Answer.append("L");
            }
        }
        return Answer;
    }
    if(E_size == 0) {
        for(int s = 0;s<S_size;s++) {
            Answer.append("U");
        }           
        return Answer;
    }
    while(true) {
        if(start[S_size - i - 1] == end[E_size - i - 1]) {
            i++;
        }
        else break;
    }
    for(int s = 0;s<S_size - i;s++) {
        Answer.append("U");
    }
    for(int e = E_size - i - 1;e>=0;e--) {
        if(end[e] == true) {
            Answer.append("R");
        }
        else {
            Answer.append("L");
        }
    }
    return Answer;
    
}
int main() {
  TreeNode* root = new TreeNode;
  root->val = 5;
  root->left = new TreeNode;
  root->left->val = 1;
  root->left->left = new TreeNode;
  root->left->left->val = 3;
  root->right = new TreeNode;
  root->right->val = 2;
  root->right->left = new TreeNode;
  root->right->left->val = 6;
  root->right->right = new TreeNode;
  root->right->right->val = 4;
  cout<<root->right->right->val;
  string s = getDirections(root, 3, 6);
  cout<<s;
  return 0;
}
```

I tried to pinpoint where the program is not working and found out that in the function `getPosition` the condition of `if(root == NULL)` is not getting evaluated.

Could anyone please tell why this is not working?

Thank you

Comment: `bool *condition; *condition = false;` in `getDirections` is undefined behavior. `condition` isn't initialized to point to anything and therefore trying to write to `*condition` doesn't have any meaning. Perhaps you meant `bool condition = false; getPosition(root, StartValue, start, &condition)`?

Comment: @NathanPierson I tried doing as you said but it still doesn't solve the problem of why its not going in the root == NULL condition. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: In C++, use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.

Comment: Maybe you want to check in `getDirections` after return from `getPosition` if `condition` is `true`, if not, then return (node not found).

Comment: @LaxmanChinannavar -- *I tried doing as you said but it still doesn't solve the problem* -- It isn't a matter of solving the problem.  Your code is wrong, and what was pointed out is just one of things that is without a doubt wrong with it.  It wasn't something you just need to "try", it was code you **must** make the change to if you're going to go forward in fixing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize either `left` pointer or `right` pointer but not both as it should be in all nodes. Thus your expectation of nullptr in uninitialized pointers is wrong. Update the struct definition

```
struct TreeNode {
  int val{};         // or val = 0
  TreeNode *left{};  // or left = nullptr
  TreeNode *right{};
};
```

Also take into account the useful comments above for getting well-formed code.

Comment: Also, `val` should be some initial value (maybe 0)?

Comment: It should be, but OP initialized them. I have updated the answer as you advised.